# Difference between gets, gets.chomp and gets.chomp!?

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between these three:
`gets` - it gets a line with '\n'
`gets.chomp` - it gets a line, but removes '\n'

Is that correct? What about `gets.chomp!` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) - it gets a string with `'\n'` at the end ( or better to say the line separator `$/` at the end) , then [`#chomp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) removes the `\n` ( or I would say the default value of `$/`),and give you a ***new string***. But [`#chomp!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-chomp-21) did the same change in the receiver or the source string itself, on which you called `#chomp!` method.

Note : `#chomp!` is a bang version of `#chomp`.