# How do I make this calculator work?

Tags: ruby

I just wanted to work on one method then replicate it to the rest. which is why one method is really only done. (kinda)

```
puts "Welcome to My Calculator! "  

print "Please place in the numbers. "  

first_number = gets.to_i  

print "Second number. "  

second_number = gets.to_i  


puts "What operation? "  

operation_selection = gets  

if(operation_selection == "add")  

  addition_function  

  puts"#{result}"

end  


def addition_function
 result = first_number + second_number

end

def subtraction_function
  result = first_number - second_number

end

def divison_function
   result = first_number / second_number

end

def multiplication_function
  result = first_number * second_number

end
```

Comment: If after solving for this for me if you could find a way to make it not look so crude and repetitive, thanks.

Comment: I would really advise following a tutorial on how to get started, a similar post  can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850598/programming-a-basic-calculator-in-ruby

Comment: This seems not that far off. Try using `gets.chomp` instead of just `gets`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
puts "Welcome to My Calculator! "  

print "Please place in the numbers. "  

first_number = gets.to_i  

print "Second number. "  

second_number = gets.to_i  


puts "What operation? "  

operation_selection = gets.chomp.downcase.to_s  

def oper(operation_sel, first_number,second_number)
    case operation_sel
        when "add"
            puts first_number + second_number
        when "sub"
            puts first_number - second_number
        when "div"
            puts first_number / second_number
        when "mul"
            puts first_number * second_number
        end
end

oper(operation_selection,first_number,second_number)
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I was looking for. I completely passed over the case option but I'm still wondering why my if statement didn't go through if you could answer that.

Comment: @Clueless I think that's why you should use `gets.chomp` instead of `gets`, and you can check the answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166108/difference-between-gets-gets-chomp-and-gets-chomp)